# Extenstion of Intermediate Value Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $f:[0,1]^{d}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d}$ with $d\geq 2$. $f$ is continuous and let $c\in (0,1)$. If we have that $f(0,...,0)<<(c,...,c)$ and $f(1,...,1)>>(c,...,c)$, is there an extension of the Intermediate Value Theorem for vector-valued functions that would help me prove that there indeed exists $x\in (0,1)^{d}$ such that $f(x)=(c,...,c)$ ?

Thank you,
JF

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are many things negating this, on being how would you define $a>>b$ for vectors? and with higher dimensions, we can start of "below" a point, and then go around it to be "above" it.

Comment: If $x$ is $n\geq 2$ dimensional, $x>>y$ would be defined as $x_{1}>y_{1}$ and ... and $x_{n}>y_{n}$.

Comment: I see, still the concept holds, as the function can go around the point without having to go through it.

Comment: How about when $\frac{\partial f_{i}(x_{i},x_{-i})}{\partial x_{i}}>0\ \forall x_{-i}$? Seems like it would simplify greatly...

Answer (score 0):

I expect such a theorem to already exist, for if it doesn't, I posit the Intermediate Slice Theorem. It makes statements analogous to the intermediate value theorem.

$d$ is a member of N.

P = $\mathbb{R}^{d}$

Q is an $\mathbb{R}^{d - 1}$ dimensional line in P.

A 0 dimensional line is a point, a 2 dimensional line is a plane, etc…

---

When moving a pair of values $(v, w)$ continuously in P, that start a finite real distance from each other, exactly one of the following two statements are true:

1. The points may become equal and unequal any number of times without becoming equal to a member of Q.
2. The points may not become equal without first becoming equal to a member of Q. In this case a $d - 1$ dimensional line segment from $v$ to $w$ must contain a point that is a member of Q.